# r; opencpu won't start

Tags: r, opencpu

I am installing opencpu on a new windows 10 box. It already runs on two other windows machines.

The library is found but opencpu is not recognized as an object, so the server does not start

```
> library(opencpu)

Loading config from C:/Users/jake_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/opencpu/config/defaults.conf 

Loading config from C:\Users\jake_000\AppData\Local\opencpu\opencpu/user.conf
Welcome to OpenCPU!




> opencpu$start(9831)
Error: object 'opencpu' not found
```

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here? Hopefully, this is basic human error, but I am at a loss.

Comment: The [GitHub page](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu) suggests you run `ocpu_start_server(9831)`.

Comment: that did the trick. Any idea why the one box allowed opencpu$start and the other didn't?

Comment: Also, if you add as answer, I can upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Jeroen has [recently changed](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/commit/6877a0cffd103677ff36301fcf691deb33441ea9) from using `opencpu$start()` to `ocpu_start_server()`. From the readme:

> To start the single-user development server in R:
>
> ```
> library(opencpu)
> ocpu_start_server()
> ```
>
> Or to start an App:
>
> ```
> ocpu_start_app("rwebapps/stocks")
> ```

As to why you see different behavior between servers, my guess is you (or someone) did a `devtools::install_github("opencpu/opencpu")` more recently on one server than the other.